# I want to receive the input into each structure variable by receiving a sentence with the fgets function

Tags: c, ubuntu, arguments, scanf, fgets

**SOURCE ::**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h> // strcmp()

#define MAX 255

struct book {
    int Book_ID;
    char* Title;
    char* Publisher;
    char* Author;
    int Price;
} book_db;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    char cBuf[MAX];  
    int fd;
    char c;
   
    if (argc < 2) {      
    fprintf(stderr, "manual : %s file_name\n", argv[0]);  
    }
 
    
    while(1) {    
    int number;
    char Add_b[MAX];
    char Update_b[MAX];
    char Find_b[MAX];
    char id[10];

    printf("\nThis is Database Book Management System\n");  
    printf("1. Add book\n");    
    printf("2. Update book\n"); 
    printf("3. Find book\n");   
    printf("4. Exit\n");      
    printf(">> ");   
    fgets(cBuf, MAX, stdin);    
   
    if(strncmp(cBuf, "1", 1) == 0){ // case1 START  
        if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0640)) == -1) {     
        perror(argv[1]);   
            }   
            printf("%-9s %-15s %-15s %-10s %-10s\n", "Book_ID","Title", "Publisher", "Author", "Price");
        fgets(Add_b, sizeof(Add_b), stdin);
        // printf("%s", Add_b); // check1
            sscanf(Add_b, "%d %s %s %s %d", &book_db.Book_ID, book_db.Title, book_db.Publisher, book_db.Author, &book_db.Price);
        // printf("%d %s %s %s %d", book_db.Book_ID, book_db.Title, book_db.Publisher, book_db.Author, book_db.Price); // check2
            lseek(fd, book_db.Book_ID * sizeof(book_db), SEEK_SET);
            write(fd, (char *) &book_db, sizeof(book_db));
    } // case1 END


    else if(strncmp(cBuf, "2", 1) == 0){ // case2 START 
        if((fd==open(argv[1], O_RDWR)) == -1){
        perror(argv[1]);
        }
        printf("Enter the target Book ID(UPDATE)\n");
        fgets(Update_b, sizeof(Update_b), stdin);
        sscanf(Update_b, "%s", id);
        
    } // case2 END
       
    else if(strncmp(cBuf, "3", 1) == 0){ // case3 START
        if((fd==open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1){
        perror(argv[1]);
        }   
        printf("Enter the target Book ID(SELECT)\n");
        fgets(Find_b, sizeof(Find_b), stdin);
        sscanf(Find_b, "%s", id);
        //printf("%s %s", Find_b, id);
            lseek(fd, book_db.Book_ID * sizeof(book_db), SEEK_SET);
            if((read(fd, (char *) &book_db, sizeof(book_db)) > 0) || (book_db.Book_ID !=0)){
            printf("Book_ID : %d\t Title : %s\t Publisher : %s\t Author : %s\t Price : %d\n", book_db.Book_ID, book_db.Title, book_db.Publisher, book_db.Author, book_db.Price);
            }
        else
            printf("Book_ID : %s is not exist.", id);
    } // case3 END

    else if(strncmp(cBuf, "4", 1) == 0){ // case4 START     
        break;
    } // case4 END

    else { // Exception
        printf("Please enter again. (1~4)");
    } 
    } // while
} // main
```

OUTPUT::

```
*@ubuntu:~/myshell/pl02$ gcc -o db_manage db_mng.c 
*@ubuntu:~/myshell/pl02$ ./db_manage db_test.db

This is Database Book Management System
1. Add book
2. Update book
3. Find book
4. Exit
>> 1
Book_ID   Title           Publisher       Author     Price     
1         ubuntu          shell           sj         1234
1         ubuntu          shell           sj         1234
// 1 (null) (null) (null) 0 -- FOR CHECK
This is Database Book Management System
1. Add book
2. Update book
3. Find book
4. Exit
>> 3
Enter the target Book ID(SELECT)
1
Book_ID : 1  Title : (null)  Publisher : (null)  Author : (null)     Price : 0

This is Database Book Management System
1. Add book
2. Update book
3. Find book
4. Exit
>>
```

**Desired output ::**

```
This is Database Book Management System
1. Add book
2. Update book
3. Find book
4. Exit
>> 3
Enter the target Book ID(SELECT)
1
Book_ID : 1  Title : (null)  Publisher : (null)  Author : (null)     Price : 0
```

If MENU-1 is a menu that puts values in the structure, the values to be put in each variable are presented with a `printf()` statement and input with `fgets`.

`printf("%s", Add_b); // check1` You can see that the value is passed from this part to Add_b, but the value is not assigned to each variable in the `sscanf()` syntax.

What kind of modification is needed to put the statement inputted by fgets into each variable in the structure?

Comment: The `struct book` contains pointers to the data. So dumping that struct to a binary file isn't going to be meaningful when you read the file later. And you don't seem to have allocated any memory to those struct pointers.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you so much... I got some help from the other questions and thank you very much.

Thanks to you you have completed the problem you are trying to solve. Later, I will become a great developer too, so I will definitely share my abilities. Thank you

Comment: regarding: `if (argc < 2) {      
    fprintf(stderr, "manual : %s file_name\n", argv[0]);  
    }`   When such a major user error occurs, after outputting the error message to `stderr`, the code should exit, NOT continue to run as if everything were OK

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  Suggest: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -o db_manage db_mng.c`  which will result in some 8 warnings.  The last line says finished successfully.  With those warnings, all that means is the compiler produced some executable, NOT that the executable is correct.

Comment: regarding; `if((fd==open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1){`  The `==` between 'fd' and 'open'  is a 'equality' operator, However, what is needed is an assignment operator '='

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: OT:  regarding; `sscanf(Add_b, "%d %s %s %s %d",`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  (see the MAN page for `sscanf()`)  2) when using the input format conversion specifier `%s` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because that specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input.

Comment: when calling: `open()` or `fgets()` or `lseek()` or `write()` always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror()` to output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred

Comment: OT: regarding statements like; `if(strncmp(cBuf, "1", 1) == 0)`  Suggest using: `switch( cBuf[0] ) { case '1': ... break; case '2': ... break;`, etc.  Suggest adding a `case 'q': ... break;` for closing files and exiting the program.

Comment: the posted code calls `open()` for the same file, several times, but  there is no intermediate call to `close()` AND the file is NEVER closed before exiting the program

Comment: regarding; `if((read(fd, (char *) &book_db, sizeof(book_db)) > 0) || (book_db.Book_ID !=0)){`  there is nothing in the code to indicate that a `Book_ID` must not be 0.  Also, if the call to `read()` fails, but the Book_ID is not 0 then the code will try to print data fields that contain 'left over' trash

Comment: regarding: `lseek(fd, book_db.Book_ID * sizeof(book_db), SEEK_SET);`  This statement can access beyond the current end of the file.

Comment: regarding; `struct book {
    int Book_ID;
    char* Title;
    char* Publisher;
    char* Author;
    int Price;
} book_db;`  writing pointers to a file is meaningless.  Reading pointers from a file is meaningless.  Suggest changing those pointers to statements similar to: `char Title[50];

Comment: @user3629249  First of all, sorry for the late confirmation... Thank you very much for analyzing the whole code and answering it. It seems that many errors and mistakes have been made when trying to implement the concept without grasping the correct concept in the grammar. Thanks to you, I was able to find many problems in my code. Also, let's implement it to make it easy to read and understand for the reader. Thank you.